# Is there any way to detect strings like putjbtghguhjjjanika?

Tags: php, algorithm, string

People search in my website and some of these searches are these ones:

```
tapoktrpasawe
qweasd qwa as
aıe qwo ıak kqw
qwe qwe qwe a
```

My question is there any way to detect strings that similar to ones above ?

I suppose it is impossible to detect 100% of them, but any solution will be welcomed :)

edit: I mean the "gibberish searches". For example some people search strings like "asdqweasdqw", "paykaprkg", "iwepr wepr ow" in my search engine, and I want to detect jibberish searches.

It doesn't matter if search result will be 0 or anything else. I can't use this logic.

Some new brands or products will be ignored if I will consider "regular words".

Thank you for your help

Comment: What exactly are you trying to detect? We need more information if we're going to help.

Comment: Even Google did not give any result for that put#@@ .Then What result you are giving ? :-)

Comment: Maybe you could put a spell checker in your search form.

Comment: There is no way to detect with a machine if a search string makes sense or not. If they enter nonsense, they will find nothing - isn't this enough?

Comment: I was going to suggest calculating a weighted sum where consecutive characters that are adjacent on a keyboard get a stronger weight, and scale the result by string length, but that'll only catch one specific type of gibberish typing.

Comment: @Doug Kavendeck you can use a similar idea in the opposite direction (look at lots English text, find what characters tend to be adjacent), and then use that to estimate the chance that some text is actually English.  It is simple and it works reasonably well.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Do gibberish searches make up a substantial fraction of search traffic, or impose a noticeable load on the database?

Comment: I would drop the idea because detecting garbage will most possibly need more computing power than executing a garbage query (which is technically correct and may even be what the user wants because *garbage* is pretty subjective, I guess).

Answer (score 178):

You could build a model of character to character transitions from a bunch of text in English.  So for example, you find out how common it is for there to be a 'h' after a 't' (pretty common).  In English, you expect that after a 'q', you'll get a 'u'.  If you get a 'q' followed by something other than a 'u', this will happen with very low probability, and hence it should be pretty alarming.  Normalize the counts in your tables so that you have a probability.  Then for a query, walk through the matrix and compute the product of the transitions you take.  Then normalize by the length of the query.  When the number is low, you likely have a gibberish query (or something in a different language).

If you have a bunch of query logs, you might first make a model of general English text, and then heavily weight your own queries in that model training phase.

For background, read about [Markov Chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

Edit, I implemented this here in Python:

https://github.com/rrenaud/Gibberish-Detector

and buggedcom rewrote it in PHP:

https://github.com/buggedcom/Gibberish-Detector-PHP

```
my name is rob and i like to hack True
is this thing working? True
i hope so True
t2 chhsdfitoixcv False
ytjkacvzw False
yutthasxcvqer False
seems okay True
yay! True
```

Comment: Implying that Markov Chains are the "background" to the technique you are using gives the impression that you are doing something much more sophisticated than you really are.  The reader requires no understanding of Markov Chains to understand your solution to this.

Comment: I've translated rrenaud's python script it into PHP https://github.com/buggedcom/Gibberish-Detector-PHP

Comment: I rewrote this in perl here https://github.com/complexitydev/PerlGibberishDetector

Comment: can anyone help me to understand what is gib_model.pki. as looking forward to having similar solutions through R language

Comment: it's just a stored version of the model, so it doesn't need to read all the training data

Comment: @RobNeuhaus    Where have you created model.... is this something a backend process of machine learning or sort of that kind of programming through which you have created gib_model.pki.

Comment: I wrote a version that does this in nodejs https://www.npmjs.com/package/gibberish-detective

Comment: I ported it to Python 3: https://github.com/amitness/Gibberish-Detector

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, using the markov approach and not trying to compute the Shannon's entropy, since in the latter 'adxcelm' would still be gibberish, but it actually would have a very high normalized entropy.

Comment: Hi Rob, could you please explain to me what you mean by "Then normalize by the length of the query". I understand that the probability gets smaller when the string gets longer, but how can this be corrected? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9):

You could do [what Stackoverflow does](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/868/calculating-entropy-of-a-string) and [calculate the entropy of the string](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/868/calculating-entropy-of-a-string/926#926).

Of course, this is just one of many heuristics SO uses to determine low-quality answers, and should not be relied upon as 100% accurate.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you mean jibberish searches... It would be more trouble than it's worth. You are providing them with a search functionality, let them use it however they please. I'm sure there are some algorithms out there that detect strange character groupings, but it would probably be more resource/labour intensive than just simply returning no results.

Comment: I think I could determine if a search is jibberish pretty well by keeping a 65KB (128 * 128 array of floats) table and basically just iterating through the string.  I am sure it's going to be a lot cheaper than a database query that returns no results.

Comment: @rrenaud So you plan on doing this for every search, even the 'valid' ones? It's not worth it.

Comment: I get a 10 character input.  So I add up 10 numbers, do a division, and compare to a threshold.  The run time computation is super low.  The biggest cost will be in collecting the data and coding it up.

Comment: @rrenaud Ok I get you... But that's some serious data collection and analysis. Way beyond my (and most people's) ability.

Comment: It's just a couple hours of hacking, https://github.com/rrenaud/Gibberish-Detector

Comment: @chrislegend If you could do a gibberish test only on the gibberish strings, you wouldn't need the test in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

I had to solve a closely related problem for a source code mining project, and although the package is written in Python and not PHP, it seemed worth mentioning here in case it can still be useful somehow. The package is [Nostril](https://github.com/casics/nostril) (for "Nonsense String Evaluator") and it is aimed at determining whether strings extracted during source-code mining are likely to be class/function/variable/etc. identifiers or random gibberish.  It works well on real text too, not just program identifiers. Nostril uses n-grams (similar to the Gibberish Detector in [the answer by Rob Neuhaus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6298193/743730)) in combination with a custom [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) scoring function.  It comes pretrained, and is ready to use out of the box.

Example: the following code,

```
from nostril import nonsense
real_test = ['bunchofwords', 'getint', 'xywinlist', 'ioFlXFndrInfo',
             'DMEcalPreshowerDigis', 'httpredaksikatakamiwordpresscom']
junk_test = ['faiwtlwexu', 'asfgtqwafazfyiur', 'zxcvbnmlkjhgfdsaqwerty']
for s in real_test + junk_test:
    print('{}: {}'.format(s, 'nonsense' if nonsense(s) else 'real'))
```

will produce the following output:

```
bunchofwords: real
getint: real
xywinlist: real
ioFlXFndrInfo: real
DMEcalPreshowerDigis: real
httpredaksikatakamiwordpresscom: real
faiwtlwexu: nonsense
asfgtqwafazfyiur: nonsense
zxcvbnmlkjhgfdsaqwerty: nonsense
```

The project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/casics/nostril) and I welcome contributions.

Answer (score 5):

I'd think you could detect these strings the same way you could detect "regular words."  It's just pattern matching, no?

As to *why* users are searching for these strings, that's the bigger question.  You may be able to stem off the gibberish searches some other way.  For example, if it's comment spam phrases that people (or a script) is looking for, then install a CAPTCHA.

**Edit**:  Another end-run around interpreting the input is to throttle it slightly.  Allow a search every 10 seconds or so.  (I recall seeing this on forum software, as well as various places on SO.)  This will take some of the fun out of searching for *sdfpjheroptuhdfj* over and over again, and at the same time won't interfere with the users who are searching for, and finding, their stuff.

Comment: Most of the visitors are kids so they just do. 
CAPTCHA is not a useful solution to put it before every search.

Some new brands or products will be ignored if I will consider "regular words".

Thank you for your help

Comment: If that's the case, then you might do all right by throttling the searches (slightly) -- as in allow one search every 10 seconds or so.  That will take some of the fun out of searching for *sdfgbpoisdfbijhaoi* over and over, but won't impact the people actually looking for, and finding, what they need.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer - Jibberish Search**

Probabilistic Language Model works.

**Logic**

word is made up of sequence of characters, and if 2 characters come together more frequently and if we sum up all frequency of 2 contiguous characters coming together in word, and sum cross threshold limit (being an english word), it is said to proper english word. In brief, this logic is famous by **Markov chains.**

**Link**

For Mathematics of Gibberish and better understanding, refer to video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l15C8UJu17s . Thanks !!

Comment: e.g. Python [2 character markov chain](https://github.com/rrenaud/Gibberish-Detector)

Comment: or [nostril](https://github.com/casics/nostril)

Answer (score 3):

As some people commented, there are no hits in google for tapoktrpasawe or putjbtghguhjjjanika (Well, there are now, of course) so if you have a way to do a quick google search through an API, you could throw out any search terms that got no Google results and weren't the names of one of your products. Why you would want to do this is a whole other question - are you trying to save effort for your search library? Make your hand-review of "popular search terms" more meaningful? Or are you just frustrated at the inexplicable behaviour of some of the people out on the big wide internet? If it's the latter, my advice is just let it go, even if there is a way to prevent it. Some other weirdness will come along.

Comment: But there are hits for `asdasdasdasdasdasd`.  In fact, there's even an [asdasdasdasdasdasd.com](http://asdasdasdasdasdasd.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can detect less common words using common bigrams and less-common bigrams.

Here is a simple python code:

```
def is_random_string(word, threshold=0.1):
    # Allow only words longer than 3 characters which contain only English alphabetic characters
    if len(word) < 4 or not word.isalpha():
        return False

    # Repeating characters
    if len(set(word)) == 1:
        return True

    # Turn word into lowercase
    word = word.lower()

    # Get list of bigrams from the word
    bigrams = [word[i:i + 2] for i in range(len(word) - 1)]

    # Get number of common and uncommon bigrams
    num_common_bigrams = sum(1 for bigram in bigrams if en_bigrams_dict.get(bigram, 0) > threshold)
    num_uncommon_bigrams = len(bigrams) - num_common_bigrams

    # Higher number wins
    if num_common_bigrams > num_uncommon_bigrams:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

For example, you can install the package using

```
pip install random-string-detector
```

Then include the method

```
from random_string_detector.random_string_detector import is_random_string
```

and finally test the method

```
words = ["asdqweasdqw", "paykaprkg", "iwepr"]
for word in words:
    print(is_random_string(word, 5)) # The result is always 'True'
```

You can find en_bigrams_dict [here](https://github.com/mehmedkadric/random-string-detector) and more details at Medium blog post [here](https://mkadric.medium.com/random-string-detection-1ed48de05a0e).

---

### Edit

The [package](https://pypi.org/project/random-string-detector/) has been updated and now it should be much easier for use:

```py
from random_string_detector import RandomStringDetector

detector = RandomStringDetector()
print(detector("Hello World"))  # False
print(detector("aowkaoskaos"))  # True
```

Answer (score 0):

If the search is performed on products, you could cache their names or codes and check them against that list before quering database. Else, if your site is for english users, you can build a dictionary of strings that aren't used in the english language, like qwkfagsd. Which, and agreeing with other answer, will be more resource intensive than if not there.

Comment: So you are suggesting he check all searches against an English dictionary? Why would anyone want to do that.

Comment: Not really, I mean small strings like "asd" or "qwe" that people often use to fill inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you just want a quick and dirty PHP solution, here is one:

```
function isGibberish($data) {
    $freq = count_chars(strtoupper($data), 0);
    $rareCount = $freq[ord('Q')] + $freq[ord('X')] + $freq[ord('Z')] + $freq[ord('J')] + $freq[ord('K')];
    $commonCount = $freq[ord('A')] + $freq[ord('E')] + $freq[ord('R')] + $freq[ord('S')] + $freq[ord('T')];
    $gibberishScore = floatval($rareCount) / ( 0.01 + $rareCount + $commonCount);
    return $gibberishScore > 0.3;
}
```

It simply counts the 5 rarest letters, the 5 most common letters, and determines if the ratio is excessive.  Tailor to your needs.