# php str_replace if filename.jpg is random text

Tags: php, random, str-replace

i have image search directory and i use filename to be title.

example, if image filename is: foo-bar.jpg
so the title is: "Foo Bar".

now, how if i got random filename like xkd345724dADGgxSDgSdgadD.jpg and so the title will be "xkd345724dADGgxSDgSdgadD", and replace it to "Foo Bar".

some php code like this?

```
$searchimg = "Foo Bar";
$filename = "xkd345724dADGgxSDgSdgadD.jpg";

if $filename == random {
$title = str_replace (randomtext, $searchimg, $filename);
}else{
$title = $filename;
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried a regular expression?

Comment: What criteria constitute a _"random filename"_ exactly?

Comment: As far as script is concerned "Foo Bar" is just as random as "xkd345724dADGgxSDgSdgadD" You need to decide how you determine what makes a random filename.

Comment: @DanielA.White can you give an example code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297991/is-there-any-way-to-detect-strings-like-putjbtghguhjjjanika look at this post. might be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski random text can not be read. ahh from your question i think its not possible to make this code.

Comment: @datasage I think it explains, that I had to define the random text that I want to use. but as you say if "foo bar" also is a random text.

Comment: @ThiefMaster yes, I've read a little, and seemed to be the solution I was looking for. Thanks All.